# Store reference to class or function in variable

Tags: swift

I would like to store a reference to a class like this:

```
var foo = Int
let converted = foo("123")
```

However this doesn't seem to work.

It will let me do this though:

```
var foo = type(of: Int())
let converted = foo.init("123")!
print(foo)
>>> Int
```

Where's the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Int` is a type, not a function.

When you call `Int("123")`, that is just shorthand for `Int.init("123")`.

You want to store the `Int.init` as `foo`, but which of `Int`'s many initializers do you want?  Swift doesn't know, so you have to tell it that you want the function that converts a `String` to an `Int?`:

```
var foo: (String) -> Int? = Int.init
let converted = foo("123")
```

An alternate way of specifying the same this is:

```
var foo = Int.init as (String) -> Int?
```

but I prefer the first because it explicitly sets the type of `foo`.

---

If you want to store the type `Int` to `foo`, do this:

```
var foo = Int.self

let converted = foo.init("123")!

print(converted)  // 123
```

Comment: This makes sense. It needs to know the type of the argument and the return type to figure out which init to use. Thanks for explaining! 
I tried doing this: `foo = Double.init as (Double) -> Double` but it gives me an error: **Expression type '()' is ambiguous without more context** Is there anything else I need to do to make this more explicit?

Comment: A variable's type can't be changed.  If you've established that `foo` is `(String) -> Int?` you can't assign a `(Double) -> Double` to it.

Answer (score 0):

With:

```
var foo = Int
```

you are trying to assign a value/reference. But you can't do this for a *type*.

Instead you can use:

```
typealias foo = Int
```

And the following will work:

```
let converted = foo("123")
```

Your code for assigning functions looks fine (assuming you're not redeclaring *foo*):

```
func bar() {
    print("hello")
}
var foo = bar

foo() // <= prints "hello"
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! 
typealias doesn't work in my case as it is immutable. I would like to be able to change the value of the variable in my code later on i.e. from Int to Double. 

The function assignment is working indeed. I must have made a mistake when I tried it out. I will edit my question.